# How to set has_many association between parent app's model and mounted engine's model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Following to [RailsGuides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) instruction, I have created an engine for blogging system in my app. This blog engine is mounted as /blog.

RailsGuides shows how to add `belongs_to` association to the mounted engine's `Article` model. However, the parent app's `User` model still requires `has_many` association to the engine's `Article` model which is in different namespace.

How to set has_many association between parent app's model and mounted engine's model?

- Ruby 2.2.0
- Rails 4.2.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the rails application, you know what module you include, so you can simply specify the relation with the class name ;)

```
has_many :articles, class_name: 'Blog::Article'
```

*check if this is the right syntax for your database adapter, e.g. I'm using this for Mongoid, but it should be the same with ActiveRecord AFAIK*

Comment: Thank you! By any chance could you provide migration as well?

Comment: I mean I don't know the correct way to create migration in this case.

Comment: `has_many` is just an hint for your database adapter (in most cases), and the foreign key will usually be `user_id` on the other side (where the belongs_to is), so you don't need any migration

Comment: ah, i see, thanks. maybe i misunderstand how association works ;)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer requires manual modification of main_app's parent model in order to set the has_many relationships to the engine's child model. So each time you add the engine to one your main_apps you would have to go into the main_apps models and set up all required relationships by hand.

A more robust, although more complicated, solution would be to use the decorator pattern in the engine so that the engine will auto-configure main_app's parent model with the relationships it needs.

By using this method you just need to add a setting to the engine initializer in your main_app and the engine will handle the rest.

**In engine:**

*blog.gemspec.rb*

```
s.add_dependency 'decorators' #this will install the decorators gem for use in engine
```

*lib/blog/blog.rb*

```
module Blog
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Blog
    engine_name 'blog'

    #to set up main_app objects via decorators in engine
    config.to_prepare do
      Decorators.register! Engine.root, Rails.root
    end

  end
end
```

*lib/blog.rb*

```
require 'decorators'

module Blog

  mattr_accessor :user_class #Can now reference this setting as Blog.user_class

class << self

    #the following lets us add functionality to main_app user model

    def decorate_user_class!
      Blog.user_class.class_eval do
        has_many :articles, :class_name => "Blog::Article", :foreign_key => "user_id"
      end
    end

  end
end
```

*app/decorators/lib/blog/user_class_decorator.rb*

```
if Blog.user_class
  Blog.decorate_user_class!
else
  raise "Blog.user_class must be set in main_app blog.rb initializer"
end
```

**In main app:**

*app/initializers/blog.rb*

```
Blog.user_class = User
```

If you run rails console from main app, you will see relationships will have been set properly. The decorator pattern in the engine can also be used to extend the main_app's models and controllers in different ways, not just Activerecord relationships. Almost complete decoupling achieved!